# How to avoid infinite recursion when referring to `config.users.users.default.home` in `fileSystems`?

Tags: nixos, nix

I have a LUKS-with-LVM drive which I want to manually mount like this:

1. Log into GNOME
2. Start Nautilus
3. Click on the relevant drive
4. Submit the password

To do this I've had to change the default mount location from `/run/media/user/foo` (which is a tmpfs, so it needs root access to create the directory after every boot) to a user controlled one, `/home/user/foo`. I expected to be able to do this as follows in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`:

```
fileSystems."${config.users.users.default.home}/foo" = {
  device = "/dev/mapper/luks-0179e7de-a468-4213-b932-ee2df135336d";
  options = [ "defaults" "noatime" "noauto" "user" ];
};
```

That results in a message about infinite recursion:

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: infinite recursion encountered, at undefined position
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I've worked around this by hardcoding `fileSystems."/home/user/foo" = […]`, but is it possible to avoid the infinite recursion when referring to the user home directory here?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is feasible to prevent the endless recursion error in the NixOS setup when referring to the user's home directory. Because `$config.users.users.default.home` is an attribute path that references back to the top-level `config` property, putting it in the `fileSystems` attribute results in a circular dependence.

To circumvent this, you can refer to the user's home directory using the `~` shorthand. This shortcut is stretched to the full route during runtime, preventing the configuration file from being circularly dependent.

Here's an example setup that should work for you:

```
fileSystems."~user/foo" = {
  device = "/dev/mapper/luks-0179e7de-a468-4213-b932-ee2df135336d";
  options = [ "defaults" "noatime" "noauto" "user" ];
};
```

Also, note that in the given setting, the `user` should be replaced with the real username of the user whose home directory you wish to utilize. Yes, that's how it is possible to avoid the infinite recursion when referring to the user's home directory here.

Comment: @Kusalananda This is a returning spammer; removing the spam link and leaving the content up is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @tripleee We are aware. This answer does not constitute spam at this point.